# Looking for IDE for PD78F0485 MCU (Renesas)

Tags: gcc, ide, mcu, renesas-rx, rl78

I cannot find an environment to work with PD78F0485 MCU.
It is RL78/Lx3. But I only see support for 78L1, 78L2, 78L3,.... but not for Lx3(this MCU).
Can you help me?

I tried with e2studio, CS++, IAR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PD78F0485 is a device of 78K0/LF3 family and is not a device of RL78 series.

[image]

The CS+ supports 78K0 devices too.
[image: create new project in]

reference: [78k-mcu-selection-guide](https://www.renesas.cn/cn/zh/document/bro/renesas-mpus-mcus-78k-mcu-selection-guide?language=ja)